# How to pass a parameter to a wsdl URL?

Tags: web-services

I know it is not the current ways of doing things but...

How do I pass a http parameter to a WSDL URL?

I tried to attach it to the end of the query String like

```
"http://host:port/serviceA/methodA?wsdl&parameterName=value"
```

but the webservice refuse to read it.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by changing the endpoint URL. (not the WSDL URL)

Thanks for you reponses.

Comment: How did u do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am no authority, but I am working with a web service (SOAP) at the moment - SOAP services seem to expect an XML Document, delivered as a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a HTTP POST instead of a GET:

```
curl -d parameterName=value "http://host:port/serviceA/methodA?wsdl"
```

Comment: Actually, wsdl is SOAP...so you need to post an xml envelope...etc